# Preventing EF from adding or updating certain child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

**tl;dr;**

Is it possible in Entity Framework 6 to instruct EF to not add or change certain entities, and instead to implicitly `Attach` them when assigned to a parent at Save time?

**Background**

I'm using AutoMapper to map to and from DTO's.  I have a model like this:

Sponsor

- SponsorId
- EntityId
- *(other fields) ...*

Entity

- EntityId
- Addresses (ICollection of Address)
- *(other fields) ...*

Address

- AddressId
- *... (other fields) ...*
- StateId
- State
- CountryId
- Country
- *... (other fields)*

Country

- CountryId
- CountryCode
- CountryName

State

- StateId
- StateCode
- StateName

I have the following JSON body sent to Web API as a DTO, converted with AutoMapper into an entity (with children):

```
{
        ... other stuff ...

        "addresses": [
            {
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 34,
                "country": {
                    "countryId": 1,
                    "countryCode": "USA",
                    "countryName": "United States"
                },
                "state": {
                    "stateId": 34,
                    "stateCode": "NV",
                    "stateName": "Nevada"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I map the JSON/DTO out to my EF model, and I step through the code everything seems fine - the IDs are correct.  When I call SaveChanges() on my context, however, it adds a duplicate State and Country.  The StateId/CountryId fields in the database are primary key and are specified that way in EF.

If I do something like this, it works (as long as I don't have TWO addresses in the same country/state):

```
foreach (var address in sponsor.Entity.Addresses)
{
   address.State = db.Attach(address.State);
   address.Country = db.Attach(address.Country);
}
```

If I do have two addresses with the same state or country, it will iterate a second time and call that "Attach" code again and throw an exception.

So instead, I've built a caching mechanism:

```
Dictionary<string, State> _stateCache = new Dictionary<string, State>();

...

foreach (var address in sponsor.Entity.Addresses)
{
    if (!_stateCache.ContainsKey(address.State.StateCode))
        _stateCache.Add(address.State.StateCode, db.Attach(address.State));

    address.State = _stateCache[address.State.StateCode];

     // (... plus identical logic for countries ...)
}
```

This is a lot of (seemingly) unnecessary plumbing that I'm going to have to do for these tables and many others.  Is there a simpler way?  Or am I doing something majorly wrong here that is causing this behavior?

I would like to simply say: "State and Country (and a dozen others) - when assigned as a child property, implicitly attach yourself when EF saves your parent record - don't create a new record you son of a bi.. gun!"

Basically a read-only mode I guess, for an entity list...

**In case that wasn't enough reading**

Here are the actual mappings

```
CreateMap<SponsorDto, Entity>()
    .ForMember(x => x.EntityId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.EntityId))
    .ForMember(x => x.Addresses, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Addresses))
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Name));

CreateMap<SponsorDto, Sponsor>()
    .ForMember(x => x.SponsorId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.EntityId))
    .ForMember(x => x.Entity, y => y.MapFrom(z => z))
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Sponsor, SponsorDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.EntityId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.SponsorId))
    .ForMember(x => x.Addresses, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Entity.Addresses))
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Entity.Name))

CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CodeState, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CodeState))
    .ForMember(x => x.StateId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CodeState.StateId))
    .ForMember(x => x.CodeCountry, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CodeCountry))
    .ForMember(x => x.CountryId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CodeCountry.CountryId))
    .EqualityComparison((x, y) => x.AddressId == y.AddressId); // from automapper.collections

CreateMap<AddressDto, Address>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CodeState, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CodeState))
    .ForMember(x => x.CodeCountry, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CodeCountry))
    .EqualityComparison((x, y) => x.AddressId == y.AddressId);
```

EF configuration for Address

```
public AddressConfiguration(string schema)
{
    ToTable("Address", schema);
    HasKey(x => x.AddressId);

    Property(x => x.AddressId).HasColumnName(@"AddressId").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(x => x.CountryId).HasColumnName(@"CountryId").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
    Property(x => x.StateId).HasColumnName(@"StateId").HasColumnType("int").IsOptional();

    // Foreign keys
    HasOptional(a => a.CodeState).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.StateId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_Address_State
    HasRequired(a => a.CodeCountry).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // FK_Address_Country
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You could also make sure that while mapping back to entities `address.State` etc. is never set, only `StateId` etc.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks. I tried that but i was having trouble making that work. However, I don't recall the exact circumstances or outcome, so I'll give it another shot and report back.  That would be great if I could avoid the nav property completely...